# Multiple interceptors in NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, interceptor

I am very new to NHibernate and have been following various tutorials online, especially [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819139.aspx) to create my own program.  I really liked the use of the interceptor to add `INotifyPropertyChanged` to entities created using the `DataBindingFactory` and tried to follow the same idea to add `IDataErrorInfo` to entities created by the `DataBindingFactory` with another method `CreateWithValidation(Type type)`:

```
public static object CreateWithValidation(Type type)
{
    return _proxyGenerator.CreateClassProxy(type, new[]
    {
        typeof (IDataErrorInfo),
        typeof (INotifyPropertyChanged)
    }, new IInterceptor[]
    {
        new NotifyPropertyChangedInterceptor(type.FullName),
        new DataErrorInfoInterceptor()
    });
}
```

The code for the `NotifyPropertyChangedInterceptor` is the same as in the linked article and below is my implementation of the `DataErrorInfoInterceptor` class which came from [this article](http://www.hightech.ir/SeeSharp/idataerrorinfo-behavior-using-dynamicproxy):

```
public class DataErrorInfoInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        if (invocation.Method.DeclaringType.Equals(typeof(IDataErrorInfo)))
        {
            var validator = new ValidatorEngine();
            var errors = validator.Validate(invocation.Proxy);

            if (invocation.Method.Name.Equals("get_Item"))
            {
                String propertyName = Convert.ToString(invocation.Arguments[0]);
                var propertyErrors = errors
                                       .Where(e => e.PropertyName.Equals(propertyName))
                                       .Select(e => e.Message)
                                       .ToArray();

                if (propertyErrors.Count() > 0)
                {
                    invocation.ReturnValue = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, propertyErrors);
                }
                else
                {
                    invocation.ReturnValue = null;
                }
            }
            else if (invocation.Method.Name.Equals("get_Error"))
            {
                var allErrors = errors
                                  .Select(e => e.Message)
                                  .ToArray();

                if (allErrors.Count() > 0)
                {
                    invocation.ReturnValue = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, allErrors);
                }
                else
                {
                    invocation.ReturnValue = null;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                invocation.Proceed();
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem that I have is that if I create an object using the `CreateWithValidation()` method and use it on a model, any text I enter into a textbox on the view is cleared when I tab away from the field (this probably happens in other fields as well but I've only tried it on textboxes).  I suspect that this is because both of the classes implementing `IInterceptor` have the line `invocation.Proceed()` if the method that has been intercepted is not one that the class is interested in.

My question is, is it possible to have two interceptors like this or do I have to have one massive class, eg: `CustomInterceptor` which has all of the methods for, eg: `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `IDataErrorInfo` and deal with them there?  That seems quite unwieldy to me.

For what it's worth, this is how I set the interceptor on my `SessionFactory`:

```
public static void Initialise()
{
    Configuration config =  Fluently.Configure()
                                      .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(c => c
                                        .Server("")
                                        .Database("")
                                        .Username("")
                                        .Password("")))
                                      .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Map>()
                                        .Conventions.AddFromAssemblyOf<EnumConvention>())
                                      .BuildConfiguration();

    ConfigureNhibernateValidator(config);

    DataBindingInterceptor interceptor = new DataBindingInterceptor();
    SessionFactory = config
                       .SetInterceptor(interceptor)
                       .BuildSessionFactory();

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not multiple interceptors. And the problem is not calling `invocation.Proceed()`. The problem is that you *don't call* `invocation.Proceed()` in your `DataErrorInfoInterceptor` when the method is not from `IDataErrorInfo` (it's correct in the linked article). Because of this, when you call some getter or setter, nothing happens.

Right now, you have something like this:

```
if (invocation.Method.DeclaringType.Equals(typeof(IDataErrorInfo)))
{
    if (invocation.Method.Name.Equals("get_Item"))
    {
        // some code
    }
    else if (invocation.Method.Name.Equals("get_Error"))
    {
        // more code
    }
    else
    {
        invocation.Proceed();
    }
}
```

What you should have is this:

```
if (invocation.Method.DeclaringType.Equals(typeof(IDataErrorInfo)))
{
    if (invocation.Method.Name.Equals("get_Item"))
    {
        // some code
    }
    else if (invocation.Method.Name.Equals("get_Error"))
    {
        // more code
    }
}
else
{
    invocation.Proceed();
}
```

Next time, try stepping through the code in debugger to see what's really going on.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I spent a good 20 minutes stepping through the code with the debugger but I couldn't see what the problem was - couldn't see the wood for the trees and all that!